# How to temporarily disable pose transformation in Weight Paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting, pose-mode

Is it possible temporarily disable pose transformation when in Weight Paint mode? Like it happens when a mesh is in Edit mode?
If it's not possible temporarily then maybe I should employ some standard tactics like somehow saving pose transformations into a temporary keyframe, clear all transformations in the original keyframe, weight paint, and restore all pose transformations from the temporary keyframe?

**Edit 1:** Screenshot based on thibsert answer

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Armature. In Object Data Properties, enable **Rest Position**.

Don't forget to re-enable Pose Position once you're done.